# É possível, de alguma forma no python, criar atributos em uma classe que seja comum a todos os objetos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

É possível, de alguma forma no python, criar atributos em uma classe que seja comum a todos os objetos? E de alguma forma se for alterado durante a execução do programa altere para todos os objetos ja criados? O mais próximo disso que eu vi foi alterar diretamente o atributo na classe

```
class Teste:
    a = 0
```

.

```
>>>b = Teste()
>>>c = Teste()
>>>Teste.a = 10
```

Nesse caso tanto para "b" quanto para "c" o valor de "a" seria 10 Porém se eu alterasse o valor de "a" em "b" ou "c" individualmente antes de alterar diretamente na classe, não ocorreria isso. Como mostra abaixo:

```
class Teste:
    a = 0
```

.

```
>>>b = Teste()
>>>c = Teste()
>>>b.a = 5
>>>Teste.a = 10
```

Neste caso o valor de "a" em "c" seria alterado para 10, porém o valor de "a" em "b" continuaria sendo 5 e não seria alterado para 10 também. Agradeço desde já

Comment: E porque é preciso que seja alterado pelo objeto? Não pode simplesmente, quando for alterar, alterar apenas pela classe?

Answer (score 1):

Na linguagem mesmo, não tem esse recurso. Para acessar uma variável de classe, tem de ser explícito.

Tem algumas alternativas para abstrair em certa medida: propriedades e usar __class__ para não precisar dizer o nome da classe.

```
class Bla:
        _a = 1
        def get_a(self):
                return Bla._a
        def set_a(self, v):
                Bla._a = v
        a = property(get_a, set_a)

x = Bla()
y = Bla()
x.a = 2
print(y.a)            # deve imprimir 2
x.__class__._a = 3 
print(y.a)            # deve imprimir 3
```

Se forem muitas as variáveis estáticas a "esconder" dessa forma, poderia partir para uma implementação de getattr() e setattr().

```
class Bla:
        class_vars = {"a": 1}
        def __getattr__(self, name):
                print("getattr %s" % name)
                return self.__class__.class_vars[name]
        def __setattr__(self, name, value):
                print("setattr %s =" % name, value)
                self.__class__.class_vars[name] = value

x = Bla()
y = Bla()
print(y.a)
x.a = 2
print(y.a)
```